# Package Microsoft.Net.Http was restored using .net framework 4.6.1 instead of the project framework .netstandard version 2 - Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-2.0

I am new at xamarin form and trying to add Microsoft.Net.Http Nuget Package in my .NetStandard type project but when i add Microsoft.Net.Http package in my project it raises some dependency issue.I am using visual studio 2017. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Screenshot.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29 Nuget  package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010  and is only required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8, or Windows Phone 8.1 when consuming a library that uses this package.

Supported Platforms:
- .NET Framework 4
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Windows Phone Silverlight 7.5
- Silverlight 4
- Portable Class Libraries

Requires NuGet 2.8.1 or higher.
Dependencies:
Microsoft.Bcl (>= 1.1.10)
Microsoft.Bcl.Build (>= 1.0.14)
please check all above mentioned condition carefully .Check your Nuget version also it should be high to 2.8.1 version.

Comment: Tnx for the info :)